# HP 250 15.6 inch G9 Notebook Ubuntu 20.04 not reconising WIFI adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

I have a new HP 250 15.6 inch G9 Notebook PC, the WIFI adapter shows and works under Window 11, but not under Ubuntu 22.04 (also tried 22.10)
I have connected to the internet via a network cable and checked if there were any additional drivers  without any joy.
The WIFI adapter is a Realtek M91127-001 WLAN CAVA2 AX 2x2 FOX
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Kind regards

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. Is it a built-in adapter?

Comment: The instaltion is not picking up the internal adapter so I have tried an USB WIFI adapter but the insalation is not picking that up either.

Comment: .... also a manual install of the drivers fails to activate the USB adapter.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.